# Does Adding "TOP 1" to a sql statement increase performance signficantly?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

In a SQL query, does adding "TOP 1" to

```
SELECT TOP 1 [values] FROM [TABLE] where [TABLE].Value = "ABC"
```

give me a performance increase, when I know there is only one of those records? Specifically I'm thinking about LinqToSql and the difference between the methods `.Single(...)` and `.First(...)`, where `.First(...)` adds the `TOP 1` to the generated sql.

The LinqToSql already *feels* slow, so I'm just trying to think of ways to make it faster.

EDIT: The `[TABLE].Value` maybe a foreign key in some instances.

Comment: You could always just try it out with a profiler.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the access rights to run profiler on this server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A TOP 1 select should terminate once the first result is found so, yes, it could be much faster depending on your query.  On the other hand, you really want to consider the semantics and the potential implication of undetected inconsistencies in the data.  Single() is really most appropriate if there really is only one match.  If you have more than one match and are using Single() you'll get an exception and be made aware of either the error in your data or in your code.  In your case I'd use Single().  To make the query faster, I would consider adding an index on the column(s) that I'm using as the discriminator.

Comment: Why not `SingleOrDefault` since `Single` will also throw an exception if no record is found?  `SingleOrDefault` will return null when no record is found.

Comment: Well, Single() essentially asserts that there is one and only one record, so if the rest of your code expects that, you don't have to go through the trouble of writing all the null checking and throwing exceptions yourself.

Answer (score 2):

My experience with SQL Servers tells me that it makes your query run much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add a `UNIQUE` index on the column?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a "TOP" clause can help in some cases - if SQL Server anticipates the query *could* return a very large number of results, it may lock the table in anticipation. If you know that won't be the case and can limit with a TOP, it won't add that overhead.

Answer (score 0):

`Single` and `First` have different uses.

`Single` is meant for the situation you describe.  You always want your code to "fail early."

If you are querying based on your primary key, or a unique index, the query optimizer is going to remove the "TOP ... N" clause anyways.

In other cases, `TOP 1` *might* have positive performance impacts, but if that's not exactly what you want to do, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a table with over 7 million records, the relative cost is much more expensive even with a clustered index if I select all the rows, I think your question could include more information about the actual query you are attempting and why, for instance, returning top 1 from a table with 10 rows vs returning all 10 provides negligible performance gains, if your table has 7 million rows, its another story entirely.

Answer (score -4):

No, it will potentially make your queries slower because a sort may have to be done first.

Comment: I don't know what it will actually do, but why would it have to do a sort if there is no ORDER BY?

Comment: Would it still sort if I'm not using "ORDER BY" ?

Comment: Why would simply using TOP 1 invoke a sort?

Comment: @Joeforker - This is why I said 'potentially'. It might not always but it could.

Comment: @Randy -- its the sorting that would slow it down, not the use of TOP.  Just because you often use TOP when sorting, it doesn't follow that using TOP itself would potentially slow down your query.

Comment: -1 if it sorted without you telling it to it wouldn't return the right answer. `top 1` doesn't mean `max`.

Comment: @tvanfosson - Yes, this is true. It is the order by that would slow it down, but typically you add an order by of some sort to support the Top n, but not always.