# Performance issue with the LIKE keyword in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have multiple records in a table that look like this:

```
       COLUMN1        |   NUMBER
--------------------------------------
'http://namespace1/#1'|     1
'http://namespace1/#2'|     0
'http://namespace1/#3'|     0
'http://namespace1/#4'|     0
'http://namespace2/#1'|     0
'http://namespace2/#2'|     0
'http://namespace2/#3'|     0
'http://namespace2/#4'|     1
...
```

Right now, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM MyTable WHERE NUMBER = 1 AND COLUMN1 LIKE 'http://namespace1/%'
```

The problem with this query is thats it is very very slow when there is a lot of records in the table. Only one record can be returned.

Is there a faster alternative to this query?

Comment: You have an index on `COLUMN1`, don't you? Also, how unique are your values? What % of data begins with `http://namespace1`?

Comment: @GSerg Yes column1 is indexed

Comment: Have you checked the query plan for the query?

Comment: @Tom WHat do you mean by query plan?

Comment: @Jean It is the way in which the engine retrives your data. In a query window of SQL Server Management Studio, press `Ctrl+M` to enable execution plan, then run the query, then switch to the plan tab.

Comment: Once you have the query plan using the steps that GSerg spelled out, you can hopefully get an idea of what part of the query is taking the most time or resources. SQL Server takes a lot of things into account when coming up with a strategy for getting your data, so you can't always guess just by looking at the query. It's best to find out how SQL Server is actually going about it and then trying to fix any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only one record can be returned, it is possible to perform a top(1). In some circumstances, a top(1) will stop the condition loop at the first match (when there is no `order by`). The query will be way faster.

```
SELECT top(1) COLUMN1 FROM MyTable WHERE NUMBER = 1 AND COLUMN1 LIKE 'http://namespace1/%'
```

Comment: This is assumption based on one record for the sample data. However, it's still wrong. TOP is applied after JOIN and WHERE. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx . Which means the query doesn't stop until it has all rows matching the WHERE condition.

Comment: You will have to explain me why the query without the top(1) (query1) and the query with it (query2) have such a huge difference in performance. The two query returns the same amount of data, but query2 is way faster (900ms for query1 and less than 50ms for query2).

Comment: I didn't see it's your question. Probably because there is only one row where NUMBER = 1 so it aligns (based on statistics). Or it removes potential key lookups (can't see because there is no query plan posted). I *wouldn't* rely on this: TOP like this can make things run a lot worse. Did you create an index on both columns as I (and 2 other folk) suggested? If not, try it without TOP. If you did, what happened?

Comment: I did create an index on both columns and it did help. Adding top(1) improved the performance even more (a lot more). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254599/does-adding-top-1-to-a-sql-statement-increase-performance-signficantly

Comment: Interesting. I agree with tvanfosson though that it isn't "correct" generally. However, if you know that there is *exactly* one row with NUMBER = 1 then you should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

You need an index on both NUMBER and COLUMN1 columns to be useful here because the WHERE clause has 2 conditions.

The current COLUMN1 index is either ignored because of the NUMBER = 1 bit, or it is used with a key lookup to get NUMBER. Either way, this explains what OP sees.

Edit:

Whether the index is `(NUMBER,COLUMN1)` or `(COLUMN1,NUMBER)` is trial and error.
I suspect the second one if there are only 2 values on NUMBER, but YMMV

Comment: How indexing going to help when you use like operator on a column?

Comment: @user751975: It can still do a stem search in the index with only a trailing wildcard. When you look in a (real) book index for `gb%` you'd know to go to g..b before you scan the "gb" range. Another way: `gb%` is the same as `>= 'gb' AND < 'gc'`

Comment: @user751975: Read the article I linked in my answer. Even if the index is not used to locate the table rows, if all data that is needed can be fetched from the index, the performance will be increased since the data pages don't need to be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Add an index on the column1 and number columns. Try it both ways, column1 and number/number and column1. Try the indexes one at a time. Depending on the data it could make a difference.

Indexes help with the like command where the % is not at the front of the like value. In this case it should help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A [covering index](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) on `COLUMN1` and `NUMBER`, either clustered or nonclustered, might be the best option.